# Unsigned zerofill in java android

Tags: android, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve a PhoneNumber from MySQL database, first I stored it as UNSIGNED ZEROFILL INT, but when I retrived it (as int) in android using JSON ,the 0s has dissapeared.
How to solve this ?

Comment: change datatype of field in DB table to `VARCHAR` and retrieve it as `String` in Java

Comment: mark my answer as right if that is what you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change datatype of the field in DB table to `VARCHAR` and retrieve it as `String` in Java.

**Side note:** It is always recommended to store phone number as `VARCHAR` in database.

Comment: Thank you , it's the solution :)

Comment: Is it recommended too to store car registration number as VARCHAR  in database ?

Comment: Yes it is. Any number that does not require calculations now or in future is stored as `VARCHAR`. Like **house number**, **street number**, **postal address**, **ZIP code**, **registration number**, **social security number**, **licence number**, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is very helpful :)

Comment: pleasure helping you